# Dockerize SDL Web Content Manager

Tags: web8.5, installation, docker

I've been playing with trying to Dockerize the Content Manager portion of SDL Web 8.5, with little success.

During the unattended install I am seeing the following error in the install logs

[image]

All my research suggests it is due to the "Server" or "LanmanServer" service not being supported in the WindowsServerCore Docker image

Any input welcome!

Answer (score 5):

SDL Web 8.5 does not support dockerization. In the future planned release we are exploring supporting docker to run the content manager, however, nothing is concrete as of yet. And indeed this error we have seen when looking at it OOTB, and we are not aware of any known workarounds.